# Not able restart freeradius server on AWs ubuntu Server

Tags: freeradius

```
sudo service freeradius restart
```

OUTPUT: *Job for freeradius.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status freeradius.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.*

```
systemctl status freeradius.service
```

OUTPUT:

```
● freeradius.service - LSB: Radius Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/freeradius; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-05-14 12:08:21 UTC; 1min 26s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 13126 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/freeradius start (code=exited, status=255)

May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Radius Daemon...
May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 freeradius[13126]:  * Starting FreeRADIUS daemon freeradius
May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 freeradius[13126]:    ...fail!
May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Radius Daemon.
May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 14 12:08:21 ip-172-30-0-14 systemd[1]: freeradius.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

NOTE:
**file permissions on /etc/freeradius**

```
-rwx------  1 freerad freerad   565 May 14 11:03
```

Answer (score 0):

It's either config or permissions.

Use the [official unit file](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/v3.0.x/debian/freeradius.service) from the FreeRADIUS project, or add `ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout` to the Ubuntu unit file, to perform a config check on startup.

For permissions issues, run the process manually with `/usr/sbin/freeradiusd -f -lstdout -xx`.  When you run freeradius with `-X` it runs as the user that started it, running with `-f -lstdout` means it'll change to the configured user... or at least it does in newer versions, not sure what you're running.